# Expectation of two default times between a period

Tags: integration, expected-value

The setup: 
Let two default times be defined as
$$\tau_i=\inf\left\{t: \int_0^t\lambda_i(s) \,ds \geq E_1\right\},\quad i\in\{1,2\}$$
Where $E_1$ is a standard exponential random variable and $\lambda_i$(X) is a stochastic hazard rate related the default of $i$. Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be independent. In addition let
$$S_i(t,u)=E\left[1_{\tau_i>u}|F_t\right]=1-Q_i(t,u)$$
With $F_t=\sigma(\left\{\tau\leq u\}:u\leq t\right)$ being the filtration generated by default events.

My question stems from the calculation of the article *Everything you Always Wanted to Know About XVA Model Risk but Were Afraid to Ask* where the following relation is made:
$$\int_t^TE\left[1_{t<\tau_1<\tau_2<T}|F_t\right]du=\int_t^TS_2(t,u)dQ_1(t,u)$$

My first concern is that the LHS is an integrant over a constant (the expectation is not time dependant) and so I think it should actaully be
$$\int_t^TE\left[1_{t<\tau_1<\tau_2<u}|F_t\right]du=\int_t^TS_2(t,u)dQ_1(t,u)$$
From here on I still have a hard time figuring out the rewriting, but I was wondering if the would hold
$$E\left[1_{t<\tau_1<\tau_2<u}|F_t\right]=E\left[1_{\tau_1<\tau_2<u}|F_t\right]$$
The intuition behind this is that the defaults what be know given at time $t$. From here on I'm confused about how to use the independence of the two default times. Maybe I'm missing a logical argument that when integrating over the survival of the second. But here is my try at the derivation:
$$
\begin{align}
E\left[1_{t<\tau_1<\tau_2<T}|F_t\right]&=P(t<\tau_1<\tau_2<T) \\
&=\int_t^TE\left[1_{t<\tau_1<\tau_2<u}|F_t\right]du\\
&=\int_t^T\int_t^u dS_2(t,s) dQ_1(t,u)\\
&=\int_t^T S_2(t,u) dQ_1(t,u)
\end{align}
$$
With the intuition being that the survival of $i=2$ up until some time $u$ depends whether 1 has defaulted or not and then looking at the default probability.

I'm not sure if this totally correct or if I'm missing some argumentation.

Comment: The title of this paper appears insufficient to find out what its authors were trying to do. Found only [https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.10377](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.10377).

Comment: The pdf is available from this site. It is then eq. 2.26 and 2.29. I hope this elaborates.
And thank you for providing the link, I hadn't thought about that :)

Comment: I cannot help thinking that this paper is full of typos. Even if it is not I recommend first to understand these notations and manipulations from the seminal paper by D. Lando, [On Cox Processes and Credit Risky Securities](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=6143) who set the gold standard more than two decades earlier.

Comment: My calculations and thought process is mostly based on this paper which is why I get the feeling that something is off. Just can't put my finger on it...

Comment: It is never a good idea to learn the basics from a single paper. What CVA is and how it should be cleanly formalized is well-known. I learned a lot from Lando and took it as a background for own developments. The paper you reading seems a reasonable overview about XVA for practitioners but that's probably as good as it gets.

Comment: I agree, Andrew Greens definition from Credit, Funding and Capital Valuation Adjustments is much more intuitive from a technical perspective and is easily expanded to the bilateral cases. But thanks for the above advice.